# Create cte to mark difference between data from different load dates

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, except

I need to create a compare and update the marking field with an indicator if a delta between load_date 1 and 2 has been found. Please advice!

example data

```
ID_person, NM_firstname, load_date, marking_field
120, Appleton, 1
120, Apple, 2
120, George, 1
120, George, 2
```

Query I currently have, but this one will update the marking field on all rows.

```
;with cte as (
     select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.person where load_date='load1'
     except
     select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.person where load_date='load2'
)
update cte

set Marking_Field='10'
```

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if a persons load_date is "load1", it cannot be "load2".
So, instead of using an "except" clause with a cte, you can use a plain update statement:

```
update dbo.person
set Marking_Field = '10'
where load_date = 'load1'
```

But, if you don't want to update the actual table, and you just want a recordset on the memory, you can use a table variable like below:

```
declare @a table(id int, firestname varchar(50), marking_field varchar(5));
select [ID_person],[NM_firstname], '10'
into @a
where load_date = 'load1';
select * from @a
```

Or if you want to stick with cte:

```
with cte as(
    select [ID_person],[NM_firstname], '10' as marking_field 
    from dbo.person 
    where load_date='load1')
select * from cte;
```